# Add and delete links to a docker container dynamically

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am running a flask application & with Openldap as the server. I need to add & delete links in running flask app container to openldap container. Basically I gave the link to openldap at runtime in flask app container. Now I want to add & delete openldap containers as I please & link them to flask application container without restarting it.

I am running the containers on boot2docker with docker-machine on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You should look at tools like etcd 
https://coreos.com/blog/docker-dynamic-ambassador-powered-by-etcd/

Comment: Can you suggest something simpler? :)

Answer (score 0):

While it's still not clear why do you want to replace the `openldap` service on the fly, it's clear that your needs are exeeding the opportunity of `--link` feature. If you really need it, avoid the `--link` and configure a full-featured service discovery.

I will quote my own answer from the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30791718/2361497):

1. Deploy some of Docker-aware DNS solutions (I suggest you to use `SkyDNSv1/SkyDock`);
2. Configure your host to work with this DNS (by default `SkyDNS` makes the containers know each other by name, but the host is not aware of it);
3. Run your containers with explicit `--hostname` (you will probably use scheme `container_name.image_name.dev.skydns.local`).

You will be able to start and stop different `openldap` containers with a similair hostname, but for `Flask` they will look like the same.

Comment: You are right, i used weave , [https://github.com/rancherio/rancher] , it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Links are now deprecated, and the new replacing feature, called "container networking" suits your needs. Take a look here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/